# Google App Engine Channel "Data Sent" daily quota for billing enabled app is 2GB. Is this correct?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api, gae-quotas

According to the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Channel

The daily quota for billing enabled apps for sending data through the Channel API is capped at 2GB. Is this correct?

I think it's too small. If I had an app that sent data every 5 seconds (at 32KB per message) for an hour, I'd be over the quota in an hour with only 90 users. This 2GB volume cap for a cloud solution seems a bit too small.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is correct. My billing enabled app shows this in the Quota Details:

`Channel Data Sent  0%   0%  0.00 of 2,088.13 GBytes`

Comment: Yes, this is the real quota.  The actual quota and the advertised quota are often slightly different.  In this case, the advertised quota is a typo -- it should read "2TB".

Answer (score 0):

You need to become a Premier customer by joining Silver, Gold, or Platinum support in order to ask for anything beyond the documented limits.

Comment: Hmmmm... Did you try this? How high did they cap it at?

Comment: nah I didn't use channel API, but .. I do agree with you.. the 2GB cap is somewhat very limited considering for a billing enabled app.

Probably you could submit it as feature request to App Engine Issue page and I will vote for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The quotas page says this:

`Is your app exceeding the default limits? If you are a Premier customer, you can request additional quota by`[`contacting support.`](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/go/support_info#cloud)`If you are not a Premier customer, you can apply for more Mail API quota or`[`file a feature request`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list)`for any other quota increase.`